# PHP AJAX and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I tried to follow this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp
I want to send the value from a select(with onchange) to change the sql query.

```
function myfunctionTime(time) {
      if (time=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","book.php?id=<?php echo $FILM_ID; ?>&q="+time,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Here is the select with the onchange:

```
<p for="session">Time:</p>
<select class="form-control" id="session" name="session"onchange="myfunctionTime(this.value)"> 
    <option selected="selected" value="12:00">12:00</option>
    <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
    <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
</select>
```

Here is the PHP where I want to get the variable.

```
// Print all the get variables
    print_r($_GET);

    // Film session or time
    $session = "12:00"; 
    $session = $_GET['q'];
    echo "Session: ".$session;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE (FILM_ID = '$film_id' AND BOOKING_SESSION = '$session')";
```

And this is the error I get:

> Notice: Undefined index: q in C:\xampp\htdocs...\book.php on line 271

Comment: Where did you define this variable `<?php echo $FILM_ID; ?>`

Comment: What does the `print_r*($_GET)` say?

Comment: I get with the print_r this `Array ( [id] => 34 ) ` that its exactly what I need because the url is ´book.php?id=34´

Comment: What URL does your code inspector show you're calling? Have you verified the query string is accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$session` value to this

```
 $session = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: He was trying to get this `$_GET['q']` yet he sent $_GET['id']. Look at the error `Notice: Undefined index: q in C:\xampp\htdocs...\book.php on line 271
`, He just updated the codes

Comment: You need to reread the AJAX portion. This is the URL he's calling `"book.php?id=<?php echo $FILM_ID; ?>&q="+time` You can see the `q` in the query string

Comment: Yer that's my mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

`time` is empty. validation is not working as it is `undefined` and not `""`. so check `if (time=="" || time == undefined)` for validation.

also in the beginning of the function `myfunctionTime(time)` check for time value like `console.log(time);`

Comment: With `console.log(time);` it shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunctionTime is not defined`

Comment: well, that was not expected. Use [debugger](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) and confirm the value of `time`.

Comment: Hey!! I just found out that the $FILM_ID was wrong and actually it was $film_id

Comment: yes, variables in php are case sensitive. But you are getting `$_GET['id']` as `34` so i did not bother looking for it.

Comment: Sorry I reply to the wrong person, now its working and refresh the page but instead of just refreshing it is giving me two pages, and on both I can see the the Array, in the first one ´Array ( [id] => 34)` and the second one `Array ( [id] => 34 [q] => 16:00 )`

Comment: Maybe its like two different pages, can I set up the first one already with a default time like q=12:00 and if I can, how

Comment: @AdriánVázquez you can use hidden `input` tag and pre-fill the value when the form is loaded. hidden value can be fetched in `$_POST`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100673/discussion-between-adrian-vazquez-and-jigar).